# Black bars in Xcode simulator for iPad Pro (iOS9.3)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am testing an iOS app in Xcode simulator on  iPad Pro with iOS 9.3. There are black bars appear on the right and bottom on simulator as shown in image. The app is working fine on all other iPhone and iPad devices. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: check constraints perfectly

Comment: Thanks @VamsiS I can't see the constraint option for the particular xib, I am using Xcode 8.3.3.